# Can I get static IP address from someone other than my ISP?

Tags: router, static-ip

I have internet service and need a static IP but don’t want to get it with my ISP because I will have to rent their equipment.

Is there a way for me to get a static IP address with someone else other than my ISP?

Comment: Who else would you get an ip address from exactly?

Comment: No. you can get a static domain name, but not a static IP. that has to be provided via the ISP.

Comment: while it is technically possible in a *few* cases, for all intents and purposes, the answer is no.

Comment: May be you're looking for a VPN / Proxy solution?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26368161/proxy-server-or-how-to-get-a-static-ip & https://www.quotaguard.com/static-ip

Comment: While it is possible to get independent IP addresses on the open market, You will need your ISP to advertise that traffic for your IP address(es) must come to it, but ISPs will not advertise an IPv4 prefix larger than `/24`, or an IPv6 prefix larger than `/48`. If you need an ISP to advertise a larger prefix, e.g. a host `/32` IPv4 address,, you will need to get the address(es) from the ISP.

Answer (score 3):

Your ISP has a block of IP address (which is a subset of the larger block of IP address controlled by *his* provider).

The traffic for that block will be routed to your ISP by his upstream provider.  Your ISP will than route the traffic for your IP address to you.

Your ISP's upstream provider, most likely, has an even larger upstream provider, who gave him a block of IP address and is routing his traffic to him.

Now, if you were to use an IP address that wasn't part of that hierarchy, there's no way for your traffic to get to you.

Comment: And if you are wondering who is at the top of the hierarchy, it is the [Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA)](http://www.iana.org/)